# undefined method 'person' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create contact manager by following a tutorial. I think that tutorial missing some part and I am stuck while writing tests.

```
describe "POST #create" do
context "with valid params" do
  it "creates a new PhoneNumber" do
    expect {
      post :create, params: {phone_number: valid_attributes}, session: valid_session
    }.to change(PhoneNumber, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "redirects to the phone number's person" do
    alice = Person.create(first_name: 'Alice', last_name: 'Smith')
    valid_attributes = {number: '555-8888', person_id: alice.id}
    post :create, params: {:phone_number => valid_attributes}, session: valid_session
    expect(response).to redirect_to(@phone_number.person)
  end
 end
end
```

My code gives the following error

```
   undefined method `person' for nil: NilClass
```

As far as I understand, somehow I need to initialize @phone_number. Since I am new to rails I could not figure it out.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Can you share the relationships between Person and PhoneNumber (if any)?, it seems a person should have a phone_number. And as you said, yes, you should initialize @phone_number first.

Comment: A person is going to have multiple phone numbers, and a phone number is going to belong to one person. Where should I initialize it?

Comment: from Dorian's answer, it seems like your tests doesn't match the expected controller behavior.  it would be best to share your controller code (phone numbers controller).

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake in controller part, I fixed it and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try finding based on the attributes used to create the phone number:

```
@phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_by(number: '555-8888')
expect(response).to redirect_to(@phone_number.person)
```

Comment: Actually, this eliminates the problem. However it does not get person from phone number.

  Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/people/1> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/phone_numbers/1>.
Expected "http://test.host/people/1" to be ==="http://test.host/phone_numbers/1".

Comment: Look at the PhoneNumberController on why it is not redirecting to people

Comment: Your controller has `redirect_to @phone_number` instead of `redirect_to @phone_number.person` like the test expects

Comment: my code is exactly the same still getting the same error.

`@phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_by(number: '555-1234')
        expect(response).to redirect_to(@phone_number.person)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(alice)
```

Comment: ` Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/people/1> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/phone_numbers/1 >  Expected "http://test.host/people/1" to be === "http://test.host/phone_numbers/1".`  gives error like this

Comment: Either your test is wrong or your controller code is wrong. If you controller is wrong, you need to `redirect_to @phone_number` instead of `redirect_to @phone_number.person`. If your test is wrong, you need to `expect(response).to redirect(@phone_number)`